# SSH error kex_exchange_identification ignoring ConnectionAttempts?

Tags: linux, ssh, git

I have a CI/CD that builds a program.
This program has several dependencies that are hosted on a private GitLab.
These dependencies are downloaded through GIT using SSH.
This private GitLab is very unstable and has a firewall that refuses several connections and many times my CI/CD doesn't work because the server refuses the connection.

I did some research and noticed that SSH has a setting called `ConnectionAttempts`, which would be the number of connection attempts, but when I get the kex_exchange_identification error SSH doesn't try to connect again.

Does the `kex_exchange_identification` error pause SSH execution on time and ignore ConnectionAttempts? Is there any way to program retries for this?

Full error:

```
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "gitlab.luizalabs.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.luizalabs.com [x5.xx7.2xx.xx] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 299884 ms remain after connect
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by x5.xx7.2xx.xx port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: `ConnectionAttempts` applies only to the [TCP/IP connection](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshconnect.c#L438) not the entire handshake protocol. In your case `ssh` is making the TCP connection fine, but to something (apparently the firewall) which _then_ disconnects it. That is not retriable. I have no idea what you mean by "pause ... on time". You might try [mosh](https://mosh.org) which is said to handle a much larger set of errors, and appears to be available on Debian.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for your comment. Sorry for my english I'm brazilian. What I meant by "Pause ... on time" is that the error kex_exchange_identification  ends the SSH connection and ignores ConnectionAttempts. I can't switch from SSH to mosh because git uses SSH.